# Is there any way to change coordinate mode of the XP pen G540 graphic tablets on a windows computer?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-tablet

Is there any way to change the coordinate mode of a XP pen G540 graphic tablets on a Windows computer?

I only have absolute mapping mode on the driver, I cannot change it in the settings, but I need relative mapping.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution !

Comment: There is available a new [Star Series G540 Driver Download](http://www.xp-pen.com/download/index/cid/5.html) from 2016-12-29.

Comment: @harrymc tryied it, but does not work

Comment: @harrymc In  case that you were looking for a solution... see my answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ! There is !!

The Star05 driver can also be used on the XP G540 (and G430 ). There you can change the input to relative mode.

Download the driver on the XP Pen Website:http://www.xp-pen.com/download/index/cid/5.html

Here is the direct download link: http://www.xp-pen.com/upload/download/20170104/Star05%20(20161223).zip